# How far can I automate Android Studio project cloning and building?

Tags: android, google-play

I've read that you could automate builds quite a lot, but what about creating an equal project and changing a few things like the app name and colors.xml values for uploading to the Play Store? I am developing many similar apps that are a copy of each other with different names, pictures, icons and colors for quantity distribution at a low price. This would be easy for a website as you could store all changing variables in a single file and then upload that through an FTP Client, but when it comes to Android software, it's obviously different.

I am looking to learn a way to make something like a .bat file or cmdline Command that would let me do this quick, and output a Signed APK ready for upload. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is probably against Google Play terms of service. See the Policy site, especially the ["Spam and minimum functionality"](https://play.google.com/about/spam-min-functionality/) section.

Comment: Hi, I've read it and although it seems like it would, these apps do offer a service to the final user that's different between owners. It's not like raw cloning but the respective app owners will publish whatever products they sell, so it'll be different throughout different apps